# Empty ASP.NET Core (.NET 5.0) project keeps using more RAM for each request done against it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memory-leaks, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I've come across a memory issue i cannot seem to find the source of.

Even an empty .NET 5 ASP.NET Core project will balloon multiple MB per second if you run a continuous stream of HTTP requests against it.

[image: Memory graph]

It will also not settle once you stop sending requests.

I've used my rudimentary understanding of the memory snapshot tool to find the cause of it but it all seems to be internal objects like `Action`, `AsyncMethodBuilderCore+ContinuationWrapper`, `Task`, `IPAddress`, `IPEndpoint`, `CancellationTokenSource` and so on and so forth.

[image: Snapshot comparison]

Searching online for the same issue hasn't brought me anywhere besides general programming recommandations against memory leaks.

Steps to reproducde:

- Create `ASP.NET Core empty` .NET 5.0 project in Visual Studio 2019
- Compile the default solution
- Use another program/script to run continuous HTTP requests against it
- Observe the memory usage growing steadily

Comment: 1) Is this compiled in `RELEASE` mode and 2) what happens when you call [GC.Collect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=net-5.0)? (i.e. add an endpoint to call that)

Comment: @stuartd nothing. The screenshot might've been a little early, i just wanted to capture the curve. GC.Collect() does not bring it down.

Comment: @stuartd It happens both in release mode and debug mode, but interestingly enough the sample i made with an empty project settled at ~370MB in one run and at ~780MB in another, after that it stuck at ~370MB, so the _not settling_ observations might turn out to be false. I'm currently running another, longer test in debug mode on the project i initially encountered this behavior on and will see where that settles, if it does at all.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that patience is key here.
I still don't know exactly what it is, but after almost 10 minutes of runtime and, depending on unknown circumstances, at anywhere between ~370MB and ~800MB any project without any other memory allocations will stop ballooning upwards on every request.

Interestingly enough, around that 800MB limit i started to encounter random `connection closed` errors in both a pure .NET loop of `System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1:5000/").GetResponse();` aswell as `while ($True){([System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")).GetResponse() | Out-Null}` in PowerShell.

While i've been writing this answer i've also repeatedly subjected the running server to the treatment of continuous connections and intermittent downtime and so far it has been stable at 800MB.
Whatever it is doing it seems to be pooling connections/sockets for reuse, as the usage neither drops nor rises now.

Comment: I believe that ‘WebRequest.Create’ is just using HttpClient under the hood. You see you’re using this ‘Create’ method in a loop which I assume is spinning up multiple HttpClients in the background. I would suggest trying to initialize one HttpClient instead of doing it in a loop like you’re doing. This is most likely what is causing the high memory usage, and eventual exceptions. If you’re using .NET 5 I would definitely recommend you look at using the HttpClientFactory pattern for dependency injection.

Comment: I should clarify that i've not used the monitored solution to generate the HTTP requests. I initially spotted this behavior when refreshing the page in Firefox multiple times in a row.

Thank you for the info on how to use HttpClient correctly, that'll come in handy i'm sure.